# Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "ChatApp.asgi".(Render..com)

Tags: python-3.x, django, websocket, django-channels, render.com

Source code link : https://github.com/ab-h-i-n/ChatApp_Django

The app is working perfectly and loading websockets in localhost. But when i try to deploy it on render.com it showing this error in log.

`

```
Nov 15 10:38:07 AM  WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 23.3.1 is available.
Nov 15 10:43:46 AM  WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 23.3.1 is available.
Nov 15 10:43:46 AM  You should consider upgrading via the '/opt/render/project/src/.venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Nov 15 10:43:48 AM  ==> Uploading build...
Nov 15 10:43:57 AM  ==> Build uploaded in 8s
Nov 15 10:43:57 AM  ==> Build successful 
Nov 15 10:44:00 AM  ==> Deploying...
Nov 15 10:44:19 AM  ==> Using Node version 14.17.0 (default)
Nov 15 10:44:19 AM  ==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
Nov 15 10:44:24 AM  ==> Running 'uvicorn ChatApp.asgi:application'
Nov 15 10:44:26 AM  ERROR:    Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "ChatApp.asgi".
```

my settings.py is : https://github.com/ab-h-i-n/ChatApp_Django/blob/main/ChatApp/ChatApp/settings.py

How do i deploy a Django chat app with websocket and channel. or how do i fix this error